# 92 Honda Accord keeps revving up and down

Tags: honda, accord, hunting-idle

This is a 1992 Honda Accord 5-speed manual.

I was driving today and suddenly my car started revving the engine, over and over. When I stopped it was doing the same thing, idling way up and then down to normal, and so on.

What could be wrong?

Comment: Possibly either a vacuum leak or binding accelerator linkage.  Not something to trifle with unless you have mechanical experience.

Comment: Could also be the idle air control valve. Again, not something to try and fix yourself without experience.